# Getting the 3rd hyper text reference from a table php

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

I'm trying to extract a specific link from a table but is not displaying anything. It's the 3rd link in the td. I thought this would work but doesn't.

here the code:

```
$site = 'site';
$html = file_get_html($site);

foreach($html->find('td a', 3) as $element) 
echo $element->href;

?>
```

Here is the HTML

```
<tr class="evenrow team-600-359">
<td>
    Aug 17
</td>

<td>
    FT
</td>

<td align="right">
    <a href="link1">Arsenal</a>
</td>

<td align="center">
    <a href="link2">1-3</a>
</td>

<td><a href="link3">Aston Villa</a></td>


<td style="text-align:right;">60,003</td>
</td>



<td>
    Premier League
</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: It's a `0` based index, so the third result has the index `2`...

Comment: Nope doesn't return anything still

Comment: Unless you give me the real link, i'm afraid I cannot say what is wrong :>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a `0` based index, to get the third result you must specify the index `2`...

Also, when you specify an index, `find()` returns only one result, so no need to use a loop !!

Here's a working code based on your html snippet above:

```
// includes Simple HTML DOM Parser
include "simple_html_dom.php";

$text = '<tr class="evenrow team-600-359">
<td>
Aug 17
</td>

<td>
FT
</td>

<td align="right">
<a href="link1">Arsenal</a>
</td>

<td align="center">
<a href="link2">1-3</a>
</td>

<td><a href="link3">Aston Villa</a></td>


<td style="text-align:right;">60,003</td>
</td>



<td>
Premier League
</td>
</tr>';


//Create a DOM object
$html = new simple_html_dom();
// Load HTML from a string
$html->load($text);


// Find the 3rd anchor
$anchor = $html->find('td a', 2);

echo $anchor->href;
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
link3
```

[`Working DEMO`](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/wij-v89)